# integrating my app with android source and compiling(my app is developed using NDK)

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk, android-source

I have developed a tuner application with NDK. Now I want to achieve this.

step 1: my application to be added in to android source

step 2: i need to compile the android source

step 3: i need to flash the output on my device.

After flashing the compiled output, In device I have to have my application there.

For all 3 steps as I told above, please help me step by step.

Comment: I understood you meant [this](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/)

Answer (score 0):

The Android app can communicate with the native code (NDK) using JNI. Follow the http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html  link to know more about integrating the Native code in Android apps. Then build your android app.

Add your android app in android_source code. May be under /android_source/packages/apps/your_app. Do the changes in android_souce/build/target/product/generic.mk, where add your new project name under the list of apps to build your app along with them.

Now compile the android source code and flash it on your device. You can see see your app on  your device.

Comment: ok thank you. now where to put ndk package? my app is depending on that pkg. do i need to put that in same dir?

Comment: First download the ndk for android. Then only you can compile your android app which talks to the native code.the above link guides you to integrate the ndk into your android app. Please follow it.